# Mongodb - Data model change, optimal way of converting array to string

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, data-modeling

Our previous data model assumed that a certain field, let's call it `field` for lack of imagination, could contain more than 1 value, so we modeled it as an array.

Initial model:

```
{
  field: ['val1]
}
```

We then realized (10 million docs later) that that wasn't the case and changed to:

```
{
  field: 'val1;
}
```

I thought it would be simple to migrate to the new model but apparently it isn't.

I tried:

```
db.collection.update({},{$rename: {"field.0": 'newField'}})
```

but it complains that an array element cannot be used in the first place of `$rename` operator.
As I understood that in an update operation you cannot assign a field value to another one, I investigated the aggregation framework but I couldn't figure out a way.

- Can I redact a document with aggregation fw and `$out` operator to accomplish what I want?

I also tried `foreach`, but is dead slow:

```
db.coll.find({"field":{$exists:true}}).snapshot().forEach(function(doc) 
{
  doc.newField = doc.field[0];
  delete doc.field;
  db.coll.save(doc);
});
```

I parallelized it using a bash script and I was able to get to about 200 updates/s, which means `10.000.000/(200*60*60)= 14h`, quite some time to wait, without considering timeout errors that I handle with the bash script but that waste more time.

So now I ask, is there any chance that bulk operations or aggregation framework would speed up the process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would go for the bulk operations as they allow for the execution of bulk update operations which are simply abstractions on top of the server to make it easy to build bulk operations, thus streamlining your updates. You get performance gains over large collections as the **[`bulk API`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/#Bulk)** sends write operations in bulk, and even better, it gives you real feedback about what succeeded and what failed. In the bulk update, you will be sending the operations to the server in batches of say 1000 which gives you a better performance as you are not sending every request to the server, just once in every 1000 requests:

```
var bulk = db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp(),   
    counter = 0;

db.collection.find({"field": { "$exists": true, "$type": 4 }}).forEach(function(doc) { 
    var updatedVal = doc.field[0];
    bulk.find({ "_id": doc._id }).updateOne({ 
        "$set": { "field": updatedVal }
    });

    counter++;
    if (counter % 1000 == 0) {
        bulk.execute(); // Execute per 1000 operations and re-initialize every 1000 update statements
        bulk = db.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
    }
});

// Clean up queues
if (counter % 1000 != 0) { bulk.execute(); }
```

Comment: Your query, is more than 10 time faster than 10 of my scripts in parallel.
I assumed a counter wouldn't be visible outside the closure. So, if I understand, the function you pass to foreach is a callback that is executed in the outers scope.
It is not quite clear to me actually how the code executes. How is the // `Clean up queues` reached at each iteration?

Comment: The parameter passed in the [**`cursor.forEach()`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/cursor.forEach/) method is a JavaScript function to apply to each document from the cursor. The function signature includes a single argument that is passed the current document to process. So the `counter` variable can be changed within that function scope.

Comment: Suppose you have 1500 documents that need to be updated, in the `forEach()` loop the counter is incremented on the first document in the stream. When the 1000th document is updated, the `counter=1000` and that triggers the bulk operation execution, which send the first 1000 batch to the server. Now, the bulk operation is re-initialised and the next 500 document batch is then executed outside the scope, more like cleaning up the remaining 500 documents queued up after the last bulk update. In essence with this example you will have two batches of operations, hope that clarifies the issue.

Comment: Would point you to these articles [**Better Bulking for MongoDB 2.6 & Beyond**](https://www.compose.io/articles/better-bulking-for-mongodb-2-6-and-beyond/) and [**Bulk Updates for All**](https://www.compose.io/articles/bulk-updates-for-all/) for a better understanding on how the bulk api works.

Comment: Of course, that makes sense. Great article, I'm going to study it (we're on Compose atm)!